# php date function calculation not working

Tags: php

Hello i am learning php i tried to use the date function to display the current time.
I have an if statement to check the current time whether it is greater than the next hour.
Here is the code

```
<?
$current_time= date('G:i:s');
$next_time= date('G:i:s',strtotime('+1hour'));
if($current_time > $next_time )
{

    echo $current_time." is greater than ".$next_time;


}
?>
```

At the time of writing this code it was 9:23:39
and the next hour should have been 10:23:39

Surprisingly i got :

9:23:39 is greater than 10:23:39

Am i missing something here.
Please help

Comment: you compare strings, not times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use a integer to work the if statement

```
$var = date("U",timestamp)
```

to get the number of Seconds since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT) thus giving you a number which you can determine which one is greater.

Comment: i did something like this and it worked : $current_time= date("U");
$next_time=date("U",strtotime('+1hour'));

Comment: i normally configure my timestamps in other variables but you have a great idea.

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind you are comparing **strings**, not numbers. 9 is greater than 1 and therefore returns true.

Either use the DateTime class to do this, or compare the unix timestamps (`time()` and `strtotime('+1hour')`)

Comment: you mean something like this $next_time=time(strtotime('+1hour'));

Comment: strtotime returns a timestamp itself. Just store time() in a variable and strtotime('+1 hour') in another.